# Group manager in SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

Is it possible to create a custom group manager in SignalR? What I want is to overwrite the default `IGroupManager` functionality of the SignalR server hub that seems only to support `Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName)` and want to replace it with something like `Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.UserIdentifier, groupName)`. Same goes to functionality of `Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync`. How do I achieve such a behaviour? If I Dependency Inject my custom `IGroupManager` in `Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` will it work? I'm using Microsoft.Asp.NetCore.SignalR 3.1.0.

Comment: The connectionId should be mapped to the userId. How would your change provide a benefit?

Comment: How do I map the connectioId to userId?

Comment: I don't recall the specifics but it should be documented hereabouts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-claims-to-customize-identity-handling

Comment: I don't think that this is a workable solution as connectionId may change if user reconnects but userId should not change. Also it does not make sense to create groups based upon the connectionId itself as if connectionId changes (due to reconnection), we would have to re-register the user in the group.

Comment: Wouldn't your custom group manager have to do the same thing?

Comment: In addition to that it would have to maintain which user resides in which group as well.

Comment: Could you tell me what would be a recommended approach to achieving this solution?

Comment: Sorry, I would need to give it some thought.